# Filter a Calculated Column Based on User Input Using SQL Oracle BIEE -

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle11g, dashboard

I am creating a dashboard in Oracle BIEE (11.1) and have a requirement to create columns that are date intervals based on a user's input. For example, the user chooses today's date, and the column run the calculation for those values based on the filter. That filter would be by the dates that are from two years prior to one year prior, returning one year of results from one year ago.

This is in the Oracle BIEE application and I do not have access to alter the database directly. So I have to do this on the application side and in an analysis.

Below is the SQL for the calculated column on the criteria tab. The "SUM(CASE" works fine, but my filter is has problems.

```
FILTER(SUM(CASE WHEN "Violations"."Current status of violation in the
adjudication process" = 'A' OR "Violations"."Current status of violation in 
the adjudication process" = 'D' OR "Violations"."Current status of violation     
in the adjudication process" = 'V' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) USING
(("Violations"."Violation Date" IN ("Violations"."Violation Date" >=
TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_MONTH,-24, DATE'@{q1}'))))
```

**The Error I receive:** 
Formula syntax is invalid.
[nQSError: 10058] A general error has occurred. [nQSError: 43113] Message returned from OBIS. [nQSError: 27002] Near <>=>: Syntax error [nQSError: 26012] .Please have your System Administrator look at the log for more details on this error. (HY000)
SQL Issued: SELECT FILTER(SUM(CASE WHEN "Violations"."Current status of violation in the adjudication process" = 'A' OR "Violations"."Current status of violation in the adjudication process" = 'D' OR "Violations"."Current status of violation in the adjudication process" = 'V' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) USING (("Violations"."Violation Date" IN ("Violations"."Violation Date" >= TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_MONTH,-24, DATE'')))) FROM "FIC - ECB Notice of Violations"

I am newer to Oracle BI, but know that this should be possible. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
FILTER(SUM(CASE WHEN "Violations"."Current status of violation in the 
adjudication process" = 'A' OR "Violations"."Current status of violation in     
the adjudication process" = 'D' OR "Violations"."Current status of violation 
in the adjudication process" = 'V' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) USING 
("Violations"."Violation Date" BETWEEN TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_MONTH, -18,date     
'@{q1}') AND TIMESTAMPADD(SQL_TSI_MONTH, -6,date '@{q1}')))
```

My goal was to create a period based on a user input. The solution was to add the preceding "date" function prior to the user variable and use the 'BETWEEN' function instead of "<=/=>." I also had to make "q1" a variable prompt instead of a column variable. You can run this in the filter portion of oracle BI or in the edit formula portion when clicking on a column.